# declare properties in constructor angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

I am a java programer that just has landed in angular 2. When doing the official tutorial, I was surprised to see that they declare this properties in the constructor instead of the top of the class.

I know that Java and JS are very different but is there any technical reason between doing like this

```
  constructor(private router: Router ,private heroService: HeroService) {}
```

or like this

```
private router: Router
private heroService: HeroService

constructor( ) {}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While this:

```
private router: Router
private heroService: HeroService
```

just declares two private properties of your class of type `Router` and `HeroService`,

this:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private heroService: HeroService) {}
```

injects an instance of `Router` (and `HeroService`), additionally creates two private properties and assigns the injected instances of your services to these in one statement.

For a better understanding, this does the same:

```
private _router: Router;
private _heroService: HeroService;

constructor(router: Router, heroService: HeroService) {
    this._router = router;
    this._heroService = heroService;
}
```

With the "first approach" you don't have an instance of these services.

Sidenote: `providers: [Router, HeroService]` which you might have somewhere in one of your `Component Anntations` just give your components the possibility to inject them, but doesn't actually do it, that's why you probably end up injecting them always via your `constructor` method.

Comment: Is there a name for this practice? For declaring the properties along with the constructor?