# Why can't I declare DI outside of construtor Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, constructor

I have a single class which is instantiated by a service (but is not a service itself) and need several services to works.
If I declare each service I need outside the constructor I get an error telling me my services are undefined.

How I call it :

```
export class MapContentService {
  public accidentMap: AccidentMapContent;
  ...    
  constructor(private httpRequestService: HttpRequestService, private translate: TranslateService, private conf: ConfigurationService) { }
  ...
  public getMapContent(): Promise<MapContentInterface> {
    ...        
    this.accidentMap = new AccidentMapContent(this.httpRequestService, this.translate, this.conf);
  }
```

How it doesn't work :

```
export class AccidentMapContent implements MapContentInterface {
  ...
  private conf: ConfigurationService;
  private translate: TranslateService;
  private httpRequestService: HttpRequestService;
  ...
  constructor( httpRequestService: HttpRequestService, translate: TranslateService, conf: ConfigurationService) { 
    this.conf = conf;
    this.translate = translate;
    this.httpRequestService = httpRequestService;
  }
```

How it works :

```
export class AccidentMapContent implements MapContentInterface {
  ...    
  constructor(private httpRequestService: HttpRequestService, private translate: TranslateService, private conf: ConfigurationService) { }
```

both should normally works if we follow the constructor logic. I don't understand why it has been override. See in this post : [declare properties in constructor angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211775/declare-properties-in-constructor-angular-2) there is no difference between the two method.

Can someone explain me what is the reason for this ?

Thank you.

Comment: why are you not use `new` keyword here `this.accidentMap = AccidentMapContent(...`?

Comment: I edited my message. Actually it was my copy/paste which was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: The two are equivalent, so my guess is that something else is wrong. Post a complete, minimal example reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was going on.
Thanks to @JB Nizet comment I did further investigations. One of the variable was initiated with one of the services.

When I declare the service in the constructor arguments, the services will be available for the variable to be initialized otherwise, when I declare the service in the constructor, the variable initialization will occure before service initialisation leadind to crash :

```
export class AccidentMapContent implements MapContentInterface {
  ...
  // The faulty line : 
  private icon: MapPointIcon = new MapPointIcon(this.conf.mapConf.ICON_SIZE, this.conf.mapConf.ICON_OFFSET, this.conf.mapConf.ICON_URL);
  ...    
  constructor(private httpRequestService: HttpRequestService, private translate: TranslateService, private conf: ConfigurationService) { }
```

Solution : I will move the variable initialization to the constructor as well.